# sql get all entries from second table when only key from first table is available

Tags: php, mysql, sql

the user should be able to see groups he has access too. I accomplished this with

```
TABLE1 groupaccess
userID | groupID
==============
 2     |    4
 2     |    5
...

TABLE2 groups
groupID | groupName | groupPriority
==================================
 1      | Group 1   |    11
 2      | Group 2   |    100
 3      | Group 3   |    600
...
```

My current php query looks like:

```
public function sqlGetGroups() {
    $groupIDs = $this->mysqliSelectPrepared("SELECT groupID FROM groupaccess WHERE userID = ?", $_SESSION['userID']);
    foreach ($groupIDs as $groupID) {
        $group = $this->mysqliSelectPrepared("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE ID = ?", $groupID);
        $groups[] = $group;
    }
    return $groups;
}
```

Currently I can't order the result by groupPriority, but it's necessary for the page, how can I get all results when only habe the userID available but also order the result by priority?

Comment: Show us the schema for these 2 tables please

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in one query using a JOIN

```
SELECT g.* 
FROM groups g
    LEFT JOIN groupaccess ga ON g.groupID = ga.groupID
    AND ga.userID = 2
ORDER BY ga.groupPriority;
```

Please remember that non PHP vanilla code like `mysqliSelectPrepared()` needs to be shown in the question if you want it used reliably in an answer

Comment: it is order by ga.groupPriority, please change that because I can only edit at more than 6 characters changed